# How to prevent menus from glitching when scanf expects an int but receives characters (C)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, getchar

Take for instance:

```
printf("Continue?\n>>");
scanf("%d", &cont);
getchar();
```

Normally I add the getchar() to prevent the program from infinite looping (reading off the '\n' character from the buffer). However, when used with a menu following this statement the extra characters are read in and any scanfs following the character input (up to the number of characters input) are skipped.

What I want to figure out is how to prevent it from skipping forward through several sections of my program when it reads in a type of input other than an int. Would this be best solved by putting it inside of a loop that won't continue until the variable is in the expected domain?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `fgets` and `sscanf` instead. Load a line's worth of input, then parse only that line instead of the entire stdin.

Comment: +1, this is the robust solution. Also, you should check the value from `sscanf` to verify the number was converted properly, or use `strtol` if you want to verify there wasn't any extra (non numeric) input on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value returned by `scanf`.  The return value indicates the number variables that were assigned to.  If you're expecting an `int` and the user types in a character, `scanf` should return zero.

Try including a `"%*s"` input specifier.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading an integer, just read a string and convert it to a number (atoi). Two problems that may occur:

1. Char buffer not big enough. To prevent this you can read char by char from the input and realloc the buffer if necessary.
2. String is not a number. Atoi will return some default value (0 or -1, don't remember). You just have to check the string somehow.

Comment: `atoi` is a poor choice for this because the return value is ambiguous. You should use `strtol` instead, it allows you to verify the string was converted properly.